# Smallest integer $N(\epsilon)$ such that $K\subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{N(\epsilon)}B(x_i,\epsilon)$

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, soft-question, metric-spaces, fractals

In a metric space, a set $K$ is said to be totally bounded if for each $\epsilon>0$ there exist a finite number of balls $B_1,B_2\dots B_{N(\epsilon)}$ with radius $\epsilon$ which covers $K$.

Does the smallest integer $N(\epsilon)$ has a name in literature. Is there any work which studied this integer in literature ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$N(\epsilon)$ is called a *[covering number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_number)* 
and it is widely studied in literature, because [it is used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_counting_dimension#Alternative_definitions) to calculate [Minkowski–Bouligand dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_counting_dimension) of a fractal.